# Can we increase interrupt number from command prompt?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, zynq

I have loaded the minized board with petalinux and on typing

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

I get something like below (not exactly, I am writing from memory, computer is not with me to copy). I get other interrupts including two interrupt from two node I created in the device tree.

```
41:   0      0      GIC 0 level dma0    
42:   0      0      GIC 0 level dma1
```

The interrupts are never triggered. Can we triggered the interrupt from the command promt of the board, for example by using devmem tool? Specifically, by manipulating the registers of the generic interrupt controller of the arm:

ICCPMR, ICCICR, ICDDCR,ICDISER,ICDICER, ICDIPR, ICDIPTR, ICDICFR?

Comment: Even if you can, you will step on the OS' feet, which may (most likely) to corrupt the OS integrity up to leading to Oops (panic). Clarify what do you want exactly to achieve?

Comment: @0andriy, I could not trigger that particular interept from the user application and I do not know why? So I am trying to understand if the propose way even posisble? I have uio driver of DMA and dma registeres triggers the intc interrupt but the GIC never triggers.